# Concatenate strings in big number apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to create a big number chart where I could concatenate a string before my number. Like for example, my number is 350 and I want to display the big number as $ 350. 
I tried using:

```
CONCAT("$",Number)
```

as custom SQL Command but seems not to work. Do you have any means on formatting the same?

Answer (score 2):

Big Numbers chart can only display Numbers unfortunately. 
Concerning format, superset uses [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format).

You can test different d3 format directly in superset with the drop down menu `Number Format` in the `Options` of Big Number (as shown in the pic)

[image]

I think in your case you're looking for [image]

Comment: Hi, How does this d3 formatting works? I referred to github repo but am not able to understand its working. For example, if I just want to put commas how will you advice me to proceed. thanks!

Comment: you mean comma as thousand separator?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that.

Comment: as shown in the drop down menu in superset ,.1% will add coma as thousand separator and 1 digit for decimal and the sign % . I guess you way want something like ",.1". But you should go in superset chart option and try it in the interface, you will understand the d3 logic quite easily

Comment: Hmm I see cool, so you're saying in custom format, I just type ,.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number format in the options field
If you create an option "$d", it will output "$350".

Comment: Hi can you tell me exact format? Should I use it like this: "$d" ? Also, is there anyway to perform comma formatting? Like 1234567 should be formatted to 1,23,456,7 something like this?